# Checking URL and kicking out of the site malicious requests

Tags: vb.net

I have a site developed using vb.net 2.0. It has a URL of like http://dgmseoc.com. I want to avoid any malicious requests using other URLs. I have tried to implement using the code below and would like to kick such requests out of the site on the page load. How can I achieve this? Any help please – thank you in advance:

```
If (urlParams.Contains("http") And 
    Not urlParams.Contains(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST").ToString)) Then
            ‘Would like to kick out of the site here.
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your web-site to only respond to requests using `dgmseoc.com` as the hostname, then you should not be implementing this in your application.

Instead, you should be implementing it in your web-server. Please consult the IIS documentation for details on how to listen on specific Host Header names to do this, e.g. [IIS 5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308163), [IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx)